# How do I add values in a list?

Tags: python

I want to be able to add values to a list. For example, I have these two list:

```
alist = [1,3,5,7,9]
blist = [0]
```

I want to insert a value to `blist` that is the value of `alist` with all values prior to it within `alist`. For example, `blist` would be the following:

```
blist = [0,1,4,9,25]
```

Since 1 is the first value in `alist` it stays the same, then I do 1+3 =4, 1+3+5 =9, etc.
However, I'm very confused about how I need to go about implementing this. I have the following piece of code:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [0]
x = 0

while x < len(list1):
    blist.append(alist[0])
```

This would append the first value at position 0 to `list2` and would make `list2 = [0,1]`. However, I don't understand how to go about in order to add the values the way I need to.

Comment: I edited your `blist = [o]` to `blist = [0]` because I was pretty sure you didn't mean `blist = ['o']`. FYI `blist = [o]` is a NameError

Comment: if you're not married to doing this is pure python, I'd take a look at `numpy.cumsum`

Comment: Are you missing a 16 in the desired result?

Comment: @cosmic: Your edit deleted all of the actual question from your question. Don't do that.

Answer (score 8):

[`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) has a nice [accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) function that does this (and more):

```
from itertools import accumulate
alist = [1,3,5,7,9]
blist = [0] + list(accumulate(alist))
# blist is now [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: Minor note: In modern (3.5+) Python, you could build `blist` in one step without temporary `list`s involved with just `blist = [0, *accumulate(alist)]`.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a list comprehension

```
blist = [sum(alist[:i]) for i in range(len(alist) + 1)]
```

gives

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for sake of completion ill add a numpy answer

```
import numpy as np
alist = [1,3,5,7,9]
blist = [0]
blist = blist + list(np.cumsum(alist))
```